# Как показать элемент через функцию focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

Есть элемент `.send_msg` (это кнопка, которая должна показываться, когда фокус установлен в поле ввода и поле не пустое). Все бы хорошо но у меня `<div contenteditable></div>`.
Вот пример неработающего кода:

```
<script>
$('.say_message')focus(function(){
    $('.send_msg').show();
});
</script>
```

Подскажите, что я делаю не так, пожалуйста.

Comment: должна ли кнопка скрываться когда фокус уходит?

Comment: Да, должна скрыватся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точку пропустил перед методом `focus`:

```js
$('.say_message').focus(function() {
  $('.send_msg').show();
});
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="say_message">
<div class="send_msg">message</div>
```